# Highcharts Bar Chart Not plotting all the series

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, graph-visualization

I'm using Highcharts in a React application to create a Bar Chart. The version details for the relevant libraries are as follows:

"highcharts": "10.3.3",
"highcharts-react-official": "^3.2.0"

The problem I'm encountering is that it is not plotting all the series data in the bars and encountered a problem Uncaught TypeError: coordinates must be finite numbers

[This is the screenshot of image how it is looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld45z.png)

Here's the link to my component: https://react-playground-practice-ed82sn.stackblitz.io

Relevant Code:

```
const SERIES_DATA = [
  ['CA 10.4%', 25419],
  ['NY 7.7%', 18850],
  ['FL 7.2%', 17679],
  ['TX 6.9%', 16871],
  ['PA 4.7%', 11425],
  ['OH 4.1%', 9954],
  ['IL 3.8%', 9225],
  ['MI 3.5%', 8523],
  ['NC 2.8%', 6825],
  ['MA 2.7%', 6641],
  ['NJ 2.7%', 6578],
  ['WA 2.6%', 6382],
  ['GA 2.6%', 6362],
  ['MN 2.3%', 5657],
  ['IN 2.2%', 5411],
  ['VA 2.2%', 5320],
  ['TN 2.2%', 5268],
  ['WI 2.0%', 4991],
  ['AZ 2.0%', 4962],
  ['MD 2.0%', 4888],
  ['MO 1.8%', 4419],
  ['CO 1.6%', 3974],
  ['KY 1.6%', 3810],
  ['OR 1.4%', 3318],
  ['LA 1.3%', 3201],
  ['SC 1.3%', 3183],
  ['AL 1.3%', 3127],
  ['CT 1.3%', 3092],
  ['IA 0.9%', 2170],
  ['OK 0.8%', 2073],
  ['AR 0.8%', 1909],
  ['KS 0.7%', 1790],
  ['NV 0.7%', 1768],
  ['NE 0.7%', 1675],
  ['UT 0.7%', 1610],
  ['MS 0.6%', 1474],
  ['ME 0.6%', 1460],
  ['WV 0.5%', 1293],
  ['ID 0.5%', 1283],
  ['NM 0.4%', 1086],
  ['NH 0.4%', 1046],
  ['MT 0.4%', 1002],
  ['PR 0.4%', 980],
  ['SD 0.4%', 893],
  ['DE 0.3%', 851],
  ['HI 0.3%', 823],
  ['DC 0.3%', 781],
  ['ND 0.3%', 679],
  ['RI 0.3%', 655],
  ['VT 0.2%', 546],
  ['AK 0.2%', 421],
  ['0 0.2%', 413],
  ['WY 0.1%', 296],
  ['GU 0.0%', 24],
  ['VI 0.0%', 13],
  ['AE 0.0%', 11],
  ['BC 0.0%', 6],
  ['AP 0.0%', 4],
  ['MP 0.0%', 3],
  ['QC 0.0%', 3],
  ['AS 0.0%', 2],
  ['ON 0.0%', 2],
  ['AA 0.0%', 1],
  ['UK 0.0%', 1],
  ['NP 0.0%', 1],
];

const DISTRIBUTION_CHART_OPTIONS = {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    backgroundColor: '#F9FAFB',
  },
  title: {
    text: null,
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: null,
  },
  navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    title: {
      text: null,
    },
    lineColor: 'transparent',
  },
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    title: {
      text: null,
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
    series: {
      label: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      borderRadius: 5,
      pointWidth: 8,
      groupPadding: 0,
      pointPadding: 0,
    },
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: null,
      data: [
        ['VA 21.9%', 99600],
        ['IN 14.6%', 68400],
        ['WA 13.1%', 59578],
        ['AL 11.7%', 53210],
        ['RI 11.6%', 52756],
        ['ME 7.4%', 33654],
        ['OR 6.2%', 28197],
        ['CA 5.7%', 25923],
        ['AK 5.2%', 23649],
        ['GA 4.2%', 19101],
        ['NV 2.2%', 10005],
        ['FL 1.4%', 6367],
        ['PA 0.3%', 1364],
      ],
    },
  ],
};

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import NoDataToDisplay from 'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display';
NoDataToDisplay(Highcharts);

const HighchartBarChart = (props) => {
  const { chartOptions, seriesData = [], seriesName = null } = props;
  const [updatedChartOptions, setUpdatedChartOptions] = useState({
    ...chartOptions,
    lang: {
      noData: 'No data to display',
    },
    noData: {
      style: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '15px',
        color: '#303030',
      },
    },
    series: seriesName
      ? [
          {
            name: seriesName,
            data: [...seriesData],
          },
        ]
      : seriesData?.map((series) => {
          let { name, data } = series;
          return {
            name: name,
            data: [...data],
          };
        }),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setUpdatedChartOptions({
      ...chartOptions,
      lang: {
        noData: 'No data to display',
      },
      noData: {
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: '15px',
          color: '#303030',
        },
      },
      series: seriesName
        ? [
            {
              name: seriesName,
              data: [...seriesData],
            },
          ]
        : [...seriesData],
    });
  }, [chartOptions, seriesData]);

  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      containerProps={{
        id: 'container',
        style: { height: 'auto', width: '100%' },
      }}
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={updatedChartOptions}
    />
  );
};

export default HighchartBarChart;
```

I am trying to show all the states with counts in highchart bar chart but it is not showing all the data in that and it is overlapping the data and showing all the data count is near by about 65 and it is showing the labels count is 22 in y-axis.

I am expecting that it will show all the series data in that bar chart. When i hover on the chart it is showing error Uncaught TypeError: coordinates must be finite numbers

[Error on Hovering Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8RTk.png)

Comment: Please don't post error messages, copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: Hi, your chart config doesn't seem to incorrect at the first glance, however is a bit unclear for me. Unfortunatelly the provided demo doesn't work. Could you please provide a reproduced issue in the working demo link?